# Can't login to windows 7 user account which has an non-english password

Tags: windows-7, passwords

My friend has a windows 7 laptop. it change his user account's password to new password by none-english characters.
Then remove that language from language Keyboad. now when he try to login to his account, he can't type his password.
I can't find 'switch user' link on windows login screen, to use his administrator account. also when I try to use safe mode, still it ask for his current user password and can't use default administrator account.
Is there a way to add a language to Language input on windows login screen without login to windows ( and using control panel , regional and language option)?
Is there any way to switch use while there isn't switch user link?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could possibly use ASCII code to enter the characters not featured on the keyboard if they are featured on the table.
http://www.asciitable.com/

To do this, you hold alt and type the numbers needed on the number pad on the right hand side of your keyboard. Otherwise, your best option might be to access the password via a USB drive with a linux distro installed and manually change it from there or use some kind of reset disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you had restore points enabled, during the initial boot, hold <kbd>F8</kbd> to access the **Advanced Boot Options**. From there, select **Repair Your Computer**.

After the Windows Recovery Environment has loaded, select **System Restore** and revert to a restore point at a time when you think the keyboard was still installed.

Note: I like the ASCII keycode idea, so I suggest trying that first if you have a ten-key.

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't type non-English characters in the password box of Windows logon screen, you can choose to remove the existing password using PCUnlocker Boot CD. So then you can log back into your user account without being required to type a password. After getting into Windows, you can create a new password without non-English characters.